# [Error]No space left on device on Tizen Emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-emulator, tizen-sdb

While pushing/installing an app to Tizen Emulator, I am getting error **No space left on device**. How can this error be resolved?
I don't see any option in installation manager related to this.

Using following command to do this:

```
sdb push TestApplication.wgt /mnt/mmc/TestApplication.wgt
```

Comment: I mean maybe too obvious - but do you have enough space to store the app?

Comment: no space available. but don't know why. I did not see any option to specify storage while creating emulator

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue was in my system drive where Tizen SDK was installed. There was no much space left in my system drive itself. I removed some files and made around 2 GB available and created new emulator. Then it started working fine and was showing sufficient space to install applications.

Answer (score 0):

can you use '**df**' cmd in sdb shell and paste the output here in comment. It looks no space available in **/mnt/mmc**.

> Also try below two methods

Is sdb in **root** mode?

If not, then
Run this cmd on terminal **sdb root on** and then try to push

> Or

Trying pushing it to */opt/usr/media*

**sdb push TestApplication.wgt /opt/usr/media**

Comment: same error. it says no space available after root too. when I saw in settings/staorage, it 0.0kb is available. don't know how to resolve this. do I have to give some parameters while creating emulator? I did not find any such thing